# Count down with until

Tags: bash

I get the issue when I give the user an option to enter a number, that number is going to be counted down to 1. I'm lost after the echo line, as the script echos the value entered but doesn't count it down to 1.

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=100
until [  $COUNTER -lt 1 ]; do
read -p "Enter a number between 1-100: " COUNTER
echo COUNTER $COUNTER
let COUNTER-=1
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `read` out of the loop like this:

```
read -p "Enter a number between 1-100: " COUNTER    
until [  $COUNTER -lt 1 ]; do
  echo COUNTER $COUNTER
  let COUNTER-=1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this using modern [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a number between 1-100: " counter

until ((counter < 1)); do
    echo "counter $counter"
    ((counter--))
done
```

- put `read` outside of the `for loop` to do it successfully.
- avoid using UPPER CASE variables by default, there's reserved for global system variables.
- `((...))` is more intuitive than `-gt, -lt...` and is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression